# viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear called - viewDidLoad not

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload, viewwillappear

I have a ViewController that calls viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear without calling viewDidLoad.
How can this be?

Comment: swift or objective-c?

Comment: My ViewController is written in Swift

Comment: You can call viewDidLoad method like that self.viewDidLoad() but it should be called when your view loaded.

Comment: yeah - that's exactly my problem - it's not :)

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having this problem in testing with ios 6 but not ios 7 and 8.

Comment: I am facing same issue.